# How to publish a message using Rabbit on windows

Tags: php, rabbitmq, message-queue

I have been trying to publish a message using the Yiiamq extension but I am not able to do so. I have installed the DLL with success but I am getting the following error code when I try to publish a message:

**AMQPExchange::__construct() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given**

Here is the code I am using:

```
Yii::app()->amqp->exchange('amq.direct')->publish('some message','Frontier1');
```

Has anybody used this extension for Yii before?or Id s there another library that I could use.

Comment: Look at the official rabbitmq site, they use videlalvaro/php-amqplib v2.1.0 https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-php.html